# How to calculate this limit without L'Hopital rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to evaluate the following limit without using the L'Hopital rule : $$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{e^{x\ln(x)}-1}{x}$$
I know the answer is $-\infty$.
I can demonstrate that graphically and by using the L'Hopital rule.
Any hint would be appreciated and thanks.

Comment: Multiply and divide by $\log x$

Comment: e^(xln(x)) = x^x might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

The key point is that $x\log x \to 0$ then

$$\frac{e^{x\ln(x)}-1}{x}=\frac{e^{x\ln(x)}-1}{x\ln(x)}\ln x$$

Answer (score 5):

Note that for $x\log(x)<1$,

$$e^{x\log(x)}\le \frac1{1-x\log(x)}$$

whereby we see that for $x\le 1$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{e^{x\log(x)}-1}{x}&\le \frac{\log(x)}{1-x\log(x)}\\\\
&\le \frac{e}{e+1}\,\log(x)
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $\log(x)\to -\infty$, we find that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^{x\log(x)}-1}{x}=-\infty$$